# reusable number input component doesn't work properly in NUXT

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an input component that is reusable and used in different places.

The number input works well and the **problem** comes when I clear the input totally, then I get the message in the console

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected Number with value 0, got String with value "".

found in

---> <Numberinput> at components/utilities/numberinput.vue
       <Createproplayout> at components/layout/createproplayout.vue
         <Pages/property/create.vue> at pages/property/create.vue
           <Nuxt>
             <Layouts/form.vue> at layouts/form.vue
               <Root>
```

Below is my code:

below is my reusable input component

```
<template>
    <div class="normal-form">
        <!-- number input -->
        <input  
            type="number"
            :name="name" 
            :placeholder="placeholder" 
            :value="value" 
            @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value) ">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        placeholder: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: "text goes here"
        },
        value: {
            type: Number,
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

and used like below

```
<numberinput placeholder="xxx" name="price" v-model.number="form.price.amount">Amount </numberinput>

data() {
    return {
        form: {
            price: {
                currency: 'NGN',
                amount: null,
            }
        },        
    }
},
```

[image: Here is what it looks like] Here is what it looks like after inputting a number and clearing the input to nothing.

Comment: `form.price.amount` is set to `null`, which is definitely not a Number.

Comment: @Jhecht what would you advise i set it to because i set it to 0 and still got that error

Comment: could you change the v-model to be `price.amount` after setting it to `0` again and let me know how that plays. I'm not seeing you define a `form` variable anywhere in the second snippet so that might have something to do with it.

Comment: @Jhecht there is a form there, I committed it when editing the question. I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `v-model.number` modifier is supposed to go directly on the `<input type="number"`. Here, the input will return you a string by default.

1. You can use `parseFloat` yourself to parse the string given by the input to a number.

```html
<input  
   type="number"
   :name="name" 
   :placeholder="placeholder" 
   :value="value" 
   @input="$emit('input', parseFloat($event.target.value))">
```

2. You create a functional component (only available on Vue 2) to inherit all attributes, props and listeners to the `input`. That way, you component will act like a native `<input type="number">` and will just add a default "type" and a `div` wrapper.

```js
export default {
   name: 'number-input',
   functional: true,
   render(h, context) {
     const inputNumber = h('input', {
        ...context.data, // Inherit all HTML attributes and listeners
        props: context.props, // Inherit all props
        type: 'number',
     })
    
     return h('div', {
        staticClass: 'normal-form',
     }, [
       inputNumber
     ])
   }
}
```

```html
<number-input v-model.number="form.price.amount" placeholder="xxx" name="price" />

<!-- Will compile down to -->
<div class="normal-form">
   <input type="number" v-model.number="form.price.amount" placeholder="xxx" name="price">
</div>
```

Comment: `parseFloat` would have been perfect, but it returns NAN when i `console.log` the data

Answer (score 0):

Although @Kapcash kinda answered the question, I still got `NAN` in the console. what I did to solve the whole issue was to add a watcher on the `form.price.amount` field, that whenever `typeof` value is a string, it converts the value to `null`.

Below is the code

```
    watch: {
        "form.price.amount": function (val) {
            if (typeof val === 'string') {
                this.form.price.amount=null
            }
        }
    },
```